# How can I access objects in the code-behind of ASP.NET in the Markup?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have the following event handling code:

```
Public Class Details
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Public veh As Vehicle

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load    
        Dim id As Integer = Request("id")
        veh = New DataRepository().vehicles.get(id)
    End Sub

End Class
```

And have tried to access it in my markup like so:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" CodeBehind="Added.aspx.vb" Inherits="Auto_Dealer_Website.Added" %>


<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <% veh.color()%>
</asp:Content>
```

but the compiler won't recognize it. What am I missing? How do I reference my `veh` object?

**Solved**

Can't reference the CodeBehind without first building the project.

Comment: its not good practice to do this. you should never mix and match your codebehind from your view.

Comment: Why on earth is that a bad idea?

Comment: you are mixing your code together and causes more headaches for code debugging and maintenance. you should be adding controls to your UI and then setting them from codebehind. Also for performance reasons as well...it will use reflection, for instance if you do the same thing and using a repeater, it will need to use reflection to get its value. do a google search and you will see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the equals sign to output the variable:

```
<%= veh.make %>
```

Comment: still doesn't work. I've also tried `<%#Eval(veh.make)%>` with no luck.

Comment: 'veh' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: OK, looks like I just needed to recompile! Thanks!